# Connecting a Raspberrypi to another raspberrypi and then connecting the second to the laptop using Xbees

Tags: python, xbee

I am stuck at a problem which is not easy. Can anyone give a basic code in python or link like sending 'hello world' from  a RaspberryPi to another raspberrypi and the same 'hello world' with some added word  like 'good' gets transmitted to the Laptop using Xbees. Consider only 2 raspberrypi and a laptop as a breadcrumb network. Consider the raspberrypi, which is sending hello world  as END DEVICE, the 2nd RaspberryPi as ROUTER and the Laptop as COORDINATOR. I have searched a lot but couldnot find anything. There are some chats apps like connecting a laptop with a RaspberryPi but no solution for my problem.

Comment: see this https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=94076 ... then try some code and come back with some attemp

Comment: Thank you. The problem is solved. If it is allowed, i can put the code.

Comment: @ManuChaudhary please post the answer to the question

Comment: @ Dragos Vasile      Xbees are a headache, but this library is the only solution https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee-python  . There are two modes of operation. One is AP mode and another is API mode. Study about these modes and decide which mode suits your application.